# how to add header to HttpWebRequest in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

`req.Headers.Add("APP_TYPE", "IOSAPP");`

I am working on a Xamarin forms app and want to get data from my webapi. When I type the `request.Headers.Add` I got a squiggy line on Add with this message

> "/Users/etgmacmini3/Projects/sample1/sample1/GlobalClass.cs(16,16): Error CS1061: 'WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'WebHeaderCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (sample1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what type your "req" object is, but if you follow this, it should get you going as far as sending HTTP requests to a Web API:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var data = "Some JSON data to be sent in your request body"; //May not need this, based on your app needs
var contentType = "application/json"; //May vary based on your app
var httpMethod = HttpMethod.Post; //or Get, or whatever HTTP verb your API endpoint needs

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://YourWebApiUrlHere"),
    Method = httpMethod,  
    Content = new StringContent(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, contentType) 
};
request.Headers.Add("YourHeaderName", "YourHeaderValue");

var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //It worked, so do something
}
else
{
    //It didn't work, so do something else
}
```

Comment: @sathish Did this help?